# TypeScript how to modify nested object patterns from one type to another

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to convert a React form hook to TypeScript (I am new to TypeScript) and having an issue with the implementation.  The hook takes in a configuration object and uses it to initialize internal state that contains some, but not all of the nested keys in the configuration object.

The configuration object looks like this:

```js
const config = {
  input1: {
    type: 'number',
    startValue: 1,
    validations: [{required: true}, ... ]
  }
}
```

The keys of this configuration object can have any string name as they are mapped to React component names, but the format of the nested object needs to adhere to a specific pattern depending on the "type" key.  I am currently using the following for the configuration type:

```js
interface StringConfig {
  type: 'email' | 'password' | 'text' | 'file';
  startValue?: string;
  validations?: Validation[]
}

interface NumberConfig {
  type: 'number';
  startValue?: number;
  validations?: Validation[];
}

interface BoolConfig {
  type: 'checkbox';
  startValue?: boolean;
  validations?: Validation[];
}

type FormConfig = {
  [key: string]: StringConfig | NumberConfig | BoolConfig;
}
```

These seem to be playing nice with Intellisense, but I have an initialization function that derives state from this configuration object and modifies it.  I am having trouble extending/omitting keys while keeping the same format.  Here is the type for the state object:

```js
interface StringState {
  type: 'email' | 'password' | 'text' | 'file';
  startValue?: string;
  errors: string;
  value: string;
}

interface NumberState {
  type: 'number';
  startValue?: number;
  errors: string;
  value: number | null;
}

interface BoolState {
  type: 'checkbox';
  startValue?: boolean;
  errors: string;
  value: boolean;
}

type FormState = {
  [key: string]: StringState | NumberState | BoolState
}
```

The function that is throwing the error:

```js
function _initState(config: FormConfig) {
  let state = {} as FormState;

  for (let item in config) {
    let initVal = null;
    if (config[item]["startValue"] !== undefined) {
      if (
        config[item]["type"] === "email" ||
        config[item]["type"] === "password" ||
        config[item]["type"] === "text" ||
        config[item]["type"] === "file"
      ) {
        initVal = String(config[item]["startValue"]);
      } else if (config[item]["type"] === "number") {
        initVal = Number(config[item]["startValue"]);
      } else if (config[item]["type"] === "checkbox") {
        initVal = Boolean(config[item]["startValue"]);
      }
    } else {
      if (
        config[item]["type"] === "email" ||
        config[item]["type"] === "password" ||
        config[item]["type"] === "text" ||
        config[item]["type"] === "file"
      ) {
        initVal = "";
      } else if (config[item]["type"] === "number") {
        initVal = null;
      } else if (config[item]["type"] === "checkbox") {
        initVal = false;
      }
    }

    state[item] = {
      type: config[item]["type"],
      errors: "",
      startValue: config[item]["startValue"],
      value: initVal
    };
  }  
  
  return state;
}
```

It throws the following error:  `Types of property 'type' are incompatible. Type '"number" | "email" | "password" | "text" | "file" | "checkbox"' is not assignable to type '"checkbox"'. Type '"number"' is not assignable to type '"checkbox"'.`

The error occurs at:

```js
state[item] = {
  type: config[item]["type"],
  errors: "",
  startValue: config[item]["startValue"],
  value: initVal
}
```

I am assuming this is because I am not directly extending the `FormState` type from `FormConfig`, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct because they are nested and interface unions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: on which line does it throw the error?

Comment: It is underlining ```state[item]``` in the following:
```state[item] = {
      type: config[item]["type"],
      errors: "",
      startValue: config[item]["startValue"],
      value: initVal
    };
```

Clarified in question.

Comment: try `state[item] = { ...config[item], errors: "", value: initVal }`

Comment: @Literphor That doesn't correct the error.  As CRice answers below, that piece of the code doesn't know which section of the type union is being utilized so a different approach is required.  That also copies over some keys that aren't needed in the new object.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs because when you pull individual properties out of the `config[item]` variable, TypeScript has to generate a single type for that property that matches all parts of the union. Eg:

```
config[item]
// has type: StringConfig | NumberConfig | BoolConfig

// HOWEVER:
config[item].type
// has type: "number" | "email" | "password" | "text" | "file" | "checkbox"
```

Since TypeScript doesn't know which of the three union'd parts `config[item]` is, the type for `config[item].type` has to include the possibilities from all the parts.

This is a problem when you try to assign back to the union, since that larger union of strings wont be assignable to *any* of the smaller string sets that each of `StringConfig`, `NumberConfig` and `BooleanConfig` contain.

--

**To Fix**

Here are a few options. Since we as humans can verify that the object you are assigning *does* match the type (even if TS doesn't agree), *by far* the easiest thing is just to cast the value to the desired type:

```
state[item] = {
  type: config[item]["type"],
  errors: "",
  startValue: config[item]["startValue"],
  value: initVal
} as FormState[string]
```

If you would rather avoid the cast, another solution is to perform the assignment in a position where TS is aware of which branch of the union it is operating on. This would mean assigning to `state[item]` inside each of your `if` branches, since inside those blocks typescript will narrow the type of `config[item]` to the correct branch based on your comparisons of the `type` property.

Once caveat to this is that TS will only narrow *variables*, not expressions. Eg, `config[item]` alone would not be narrowed, but if you assign it to a variable: `const itemConfig = config[item]`, TS can narrow the type of the `itemConfig` variable.

In practice, this might look like:

```
function _initState(config: FormConfig) {
  let state = {} as FormState;

  for (let item in config) {
    let initVal = null;

    // Note that to track the correct part of the union, you need
    // to assign to a variable, rather than just using `config[item]`
    const itemConfig = config[item];

    if (itemConfig["startValue"] !== undefined) {
      if (
        itemConfig["type"] === "email" ||
        itemConfig["type"] === "password" ||
        itemConfig["type"] === "text" ||
        itemConfig["type"] === "file"
      ) {
        initVal = String(itemConfig["startValue"]);

        // Assign it here, since typescript is now aware that
        // itemConfig is specifically a `StringConfig`.
        state[item] = {
          type: itemConfig["type"],
          errors: "",
          startValue: itemConfig["startValue"],
          value: initVal
        }

      } else if (itemConfig["type"] === "number") {
        // assign here for NumberConfig
      }
      // ... and so on

    }
  }

  return state;
}
```

Although personally I would recommend the first approach.

---

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-BzhqSNes+SXsf2hEBoMMeTyFDsc-3o0WTXhoORZAARDK9pBOBOQwAAhAQRCkGgUASLgUBoE+fQ-le-7TjhuEwIBkjASwoEQa0sGEEhMDgVyOjgQY+iEbhJFCGRmhgeBVFwUhRDgcYZgWFYTH6CxRE-uxnEUTx7LUfxdEOCAYkSZJxHzjJ3G8TRAmSuBrEwNh6m3uOAQIs2kSzppIHcVBKawSu0S4buUBICYsB-gBNnkdp8l8bR4HOqw4HGepb7mUQRpsNZD4cbZEH2XKjnOT+rnuZ5+HSQlcnQApgWXNctz3KFZqSRFyAIuGXy4LFQE5UlDopYZhQuTAbkeWVP5eQRJnZb5lH+bpdEMUgqmGfI-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-lz5J08UyphvLcspCxf2XN3VeR0-5s29DvEy+RkbtQyofO+39S65zooVeMJVm7dSvtdLsnxvhoIgQ-KBT954+Exq-IewDR732XrxGBuEAF0SAe-EB0Ft6MJPo-denCt6LwIUgXeyNubIM6sPVBid0Hj0wWnbkRdyq8I2ltOiC0C7KO+qo0+21K7aJbrohRjciJ4N-CIhElNAZPGZIPLqI9P7HzUQI9+bDZ7AIXuAuu-CWE-iEZzAIYiWqSJBqQuuCjz7mMCYQt2-dqFQHsdI3CDC5FMN-sA9xHD35eOcSvQYDlXEmQCfA9SiCQkdTCXkhR2DoYX3CpYogiMPI2K3DQ3yb936pLIek2afj5BZP6VwlMi9dG+OASUkRwT97cz6CLMW8gJZSxlm0+WBQgA)

Comment: Both of these seem to work great.  I found another solution, but this is much more elegant.  Still getting my head wrapped around casting when I know more than the compiler.  Thank you!